# What is this chilli plant?

Tags: identification, chili

Does anyone know what type of chilli plant is this? My uncle gave this plant to me back in July this year and he said he thought it was a Thai fire chilli. I have a chilli plant that I identified as a Thai fire chilli and the leaves are not that big. It has not started to flower yet. Below are some photos I took today.

[image]

Comment: Is this a plant that your uncle grew himself from seed he collected from his own plants the previous year? Or is it a plant he bought somewhere?

Comment: Maybe you should wait until it has peppers, and then ask again.

Comment: Bamboo, my uncle grew the plant from seeds. I am not sure where he got the seeds from. I know I should probably wait until it has peppers, but I just want to get some information about the pant.

Comment: If they're seeds he collected himself, then the plant could be any kind of chili - they don't come true from seed unless grown in closed conditions so they don't cross pollinate. You'll just have to wait to see what it produces I'm afraid, and even then, it might not be one you can actuallly buy somewhere